# Xamarin.Android Card View Elevation not showing

Tags: android, xamarin.android, cardview

I have a CardView inside a RecyclerView however the card elevation is not showing the shadow.

I've tried using clipToPadding as suggested in other answers aswell as playing around with paddings on the parent ViewGroup but to no avail. 
I've posted the two relevant layout files below.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Layout containing RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
  <ProgressBar
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="80dp"
  android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
  android:indeterminate="true"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_margin="30dp"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:background="@drawable/ProgressBarStyle"
  android:visibility="visible" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textGuest"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:visibility="gone"
  android:text="Please sign in to start saving your favourite recipes"
  android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
  android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Card View Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardElevation="0.7dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/PaleGreen">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_margin="2dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeNameTextView"
        android:layout_below="@id/photoImageView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> card elevation is not showing the shadow.

I have tested your code. The shadow is showing. You only set 0.7dp, so it looks like not showing. Please try to use a larger value.

For example, 0.7dp looks like:
[image: 0.7dp]

5dp:
[image]

And 10dp:
[image]

Comment: @Nick Does this help you?